# How to create device driver for nested partitions?

Tags: linux, partitioning, fdisk

I'm running MSWindows virtualized with /dev/sda2 as it's primary drive.
Consequently, there is a partition table on that partition, shown as:

```
# fdisk -l /dev/sda2

Disk /dev/sda2: 137.4 GB, 137436203520 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 16709 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

     Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda2p1   *           1       16708   134206978+   7  HPFS/NTFS
```

So my question is simply: **What are the major/minor numbers to create /dev/sda2p1**?
What about sda2p2 and sda3p1?

Comment: Running: **CentOS release 5.3 (Final)**, kernel: **2.6.18-128.1.10.el5**

Comment: What are you using for your virtualization?

Comment: @heavyd - KVM (version 36)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is a straight disk image (e.g., your virtualization solution is not adding some extra metadata to things), [this document](http://wiki.edseek.com/guide:mount_loopback) (also [here](http://www.unix.com/filesystems-disks-memory/24366-can-loopback-filesystem-partitioned.html)) offers some suggestions for accessing your partitions on /dev/sda2 (summary: use the `-o offset` option to `losetup` to create a new block device referencing the appropriate offset into sda2).

You can also use the Network Block Device (NBD) to create a partitioned block device from /dev/sda2, see [this LWN article](http://lwn.net/Articles/276044/) which described the process in detail.  And hey, I just learned something new.

Comment: Yes, I realized I could use loopback/offset after I posted and found out that I don't have an NTFS module in my kernel (d'oh). I used the same technique (elsewhere on Ubuntu) to share a "virtual USB flash drive" with the host & a VM.  Tedious, but it worked; however I didn't use */etc/fstab* then.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want here is kpartx.

https://nfolamp.wordpress.com/2010/08/16/mounting-raw-image-files-and-kpartx/

Kpartx takes a raw disk image and produces devices in the root file system for each of the partitions found in the disk image, (ie, in it's partition table).

Comment: ps, for added fun and excitement, put your partition table on a partition located on LVM, and nest the LVMs too.

http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/329343/unwrapping-an-lvm2-recurrence

Comment: You need to explain some details to help the users understand

Comment: Rich, you can also update your own answer in order to add information rather than commenting below it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `losetup -P` (`--partscan`) to access the partitions as `/dev/loopXpY` without needing to manually pass `-o` offsets (not sure if this was possible [back in 2009](https://superuser.com/a/83329)):

```
# losetup -Pf --show /dev/sda2
/dev/loop0
$ ls /dev/loop0p*
/dev/loop0p1
```